# 'New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I am setting up a SharePoint 2013 Search Centre via PowerShell scripts. I can content sources, crawl rules, etc. and all that seems to work fine, but I can't create a "ResultSource":

```
PS > New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource
New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource : The term 'New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

which is weird. It looks like those cmdlet at the bottom of the list [New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn495335.aspx) are just not there: I have functions for "SearchResultItemType(s)", but not "SearchResultSrouce(s)".

```
PS > Get-Command -Module *Sharepoint* -name *SearchResult*

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Cmdlet          Get-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType               Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Cmdlet          New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType               Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Cmdlet          Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType            Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Cmdlet          Set-SPEnterpriseSearchResultItemType               Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

You must load assembly to Search

```
 [void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search")
```

basic code as below

```
$publishingSite = Get-SPSite "http://c4968397007:1000/"
$sspApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication;

# load Search assembly

[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search")

# create manager instances

$fedManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager($sspApp)
$searchOwner = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectOwner([Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectLevel]::Ssa, $publishingSite.RootWeb)

# define query

$query = '{searchTerms?}'
$queryProperties = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryTransformProperties
# define custom sorting
$sortCollection = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortCollection
$sortCollection.Add("Title", [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection]::Ascending)
$queryProperties["SortList"] = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortCollection]$sortCollection

# create result source
$resultSource = $fedManager.CreateSource($searchOwner)
$resultSource.Name = 'Result Source Through PowerShell'
$resultSource.ProviderId = $fedManager.ListProviders()['Local SharePoint Provider'].Id
$resultSource.CreateQueryTransform($queryProperties, $query)

$resultSource.Commit()
```

You can see more this [link](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-2013-configure-content-source-and-search-result-source)

Comment: Hiya - thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. It loads fine (version v4.0.30319 ?) but then still doesn't recognise the term 'New-SPEnterpriseSearchResultSource'.